# Optimizing the filling of lists from a .txt file

Tags: python, list

I am currently working on a post processing program for which I use a .txt file. This text file contains 4 informations that are repeated 8 times on each line. I created a function to get these informations and store them in lists in the simplest way :

```
def add_to_lists(line, frequence, phase, in_phase, in_quad) :
        
        # Serie 1 - Even
        frequence[0].append(line[3])
        in_phase[0].append(line[4])
        in_quad[0].append(line[5])
        phase[0].append(line[6])
        
        frequence[1].append(line[7])
        in_phase[1].append(line[8])
        in_quad[1].append(line[9])
        phase[1].append(line[10])
        
        frequence[2].append(line[11])
        in_phase[2].append(line[12])
        in_quad[2].append(line[13])
        phase[2].append(line[14])
        
        frequence[3].append(line[15])
        in_phase[3].append(line[16])
        in_quad[3].append(line[17])
        phase[3].append(line[18])
        
        # Serie 2 - Odd
        frequence[4].append(line[19])
        in_phase[4].append(line[20])
        in_quad[4].append(line[21])
        phase[4].append(line[22])
        
        frequence[5].append(line[23])
        in_phase[5].append(line[24])
        in_quad[5].append(line[25])
        phase[5].append(line[26])
        
        frequence[6].append(line[27])
        in_phase[6].append(line[28])
        in_quad[6].append(line[29])
        phase[6].append(line[30])
        
        frequence[7].append(line[31])
        in_phase[7].append(line[32])
        in_quad[7].append(line[33])
        phase[7].append(line[34])
```

This method works fine but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of filling in those lists.

Comment: Please show us how your variables/data looks like before putting it into the function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a generator to create chunks...

```py
def chunked(elements, size, start_index=0, limit=None):
    """ Generator creating chunks of given size. """

    if limit == 0:
        return

    for chunk_index, i in enumerate(range(start_index, len(elements), size)):
        if limit is None or chunk_index < limit:
            yield (chunk_index, elements[i:i+size])
        else:
            break


def add_to_lists(line, frequence, phase, in_phase, in_quad):

    for i, data in chunked(line, 4, 3, 8):

        frequence[i].append(data[0])
        in_phase[i].append(data[1])
        in_quad[i].append(data[2])
        phase[i].append(data[3])
```

---

**I think using a generator**, as in this and chatax' answers used, **is more readable, reusable and testable**. It separates distinct behaviours.

1. Creating 8 Chunks
2. Fill Arrays

That said, the generator `chunked` can easily be tested, e.g. with an unit test.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about ```yield```but I will sure look it up and try your method.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of popping out which may be dangerous, you can simply use a step in your for loop, and divide the loop index by the step.

```
def add_to_lists(line, frequence, phase, in_phase, in_quad, step=4) :
        
    for i in range(3, len(line), step):
            
            idx = (i-3) // step

            frequence[idx].append(line[i])
            in_phase[idx].append(line[i+1])
            in_quad[idx].append(line[i+2])
            phase[idx].append(line[i+3])
```

Comment: I tried this method but the last index is out of range... I am working on it. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @EmmaFM if the last index is out of range, just change len(line) by len(line)-1.

Answer (score 1):

You could chunk your line variable into sublists of length 4. You can simply `pip install more-itertools` and import `chunked` from this package.

```
from more_itertools import chunked

line_chunks = chunked(line[3:], 4)
for i, line_chunk in enumerate(line_chunks):
    frequence[i].append(line_chunk[0])
    in_phase[i].append(line_chunk[1])
    in_quad[i].append(line_chunk[2])
    phase[i].append(line_chunk[3])
```

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of `more_itertools`. :) You may need to add a `break` after 8 chunks as we do not know if the list `line` has exact 35 or more elements, or use `line[3:35]`.

Comment: You are welcome! A break is not necessairy when line[3:] has a length that is perfectly dividable by 4. Otherwise you are right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I can not pip install something as I am working on a common server and I am not admin, but I will definitely keep it in mind

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import islice
def add_to_list(line, frequence, phase, in_phase, in_quad):
    frequence.extend(islice(line, 0, None, 4))
    in_phase.extend(islice(line, 1, None, 4))
    in_quad.extend(islice(line, 2, None, 4))
    phase.extend(islice(line, 3, None, 4))
```

You could just return a tuple of every thing, like this

```
def add_to_list(line):
    return (list(islice(line, 0, None, 4)),
            list(islice(line, 1, None, 4)),
            list(islice(line, 2, None, 4)),
            list(islice(line, 3, None, 4)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I can not pip install itertools but I will keep it in mind for my own projects in the future

Comment: @EmmaFM no need to install itertools, it comes with standard python.  Just import it.

Answer (score -2):

You could pop the values from the `line` list (i.e. get the fourth item in this case and remove it)

```py
for i in range(8):
   frequence[i].append(line.pop(3))
   in_phase[i].append(line.pop(3))
   in_quad[i].append(line.pop(3))
   phase[i].append(line.pop(3))
```

Edit: While this works, popping the list undeniably affects it. If this is unintended (or you don't know if you should), stepping with range() is a better option